# accessing some arbitrary element in array in templates

Tags: go, go-templates, consul

I need to access some arbitrary element in array in template.

I have a function that returns an array of 3 elements and I want to access only the second element. How do I do that?

the template:

```
test start
{{ service "mongodb" }}
test end
```

results in:

```
test start 
[0xc208062de0 0xc208062d80 0xc208062e40] 
test end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think predefined global function `index` could help here, documentation from package [template](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/)

```
index   
Returns the result of indexing its first argument by the
following arguments. Thus "index x 1 2 3" is, in Go syntax,     
x[1][2][3]. Each indexed item must be a map, slice, or array.
```

Here is an example;

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func returnArray(dummy string) []int {
    return []int{11, 22, 33}
}

func main() {
    funcMap := template.FuncMap{
        "myFunc": returnArray,
    }

    const templateText = `
    Output 0: {{myFunc "abc"}}
    Output 1: {{index (myFunc "abc") 0}}
    Output 2: {{index (myFunc "abc") 1}}
    Output 3: {{index (myFunc "abc") 2}}
    `

    tmpl, err := template.New("myFuncTest").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(templateText)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("parsing: %s", err)
    }

    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, "")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("execution: %s", err)
    }
}
```

Output

```
Output 0: [11 22 33]
Output 1: 11
Output 2: 22
Output 3: 33
```